# Is the tElement in the Angular directive compile function a jQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was looking at another SO directive exercise for duplicating an element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Directive Lifecycle</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <double>
    <h1>Ask Jeebus</h1>
  </double>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('double', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(tElement, attrs) {
            var content = tElement.children();
            tElement.append(content.clone());
            tElement.replaceWith(tElement.children());
        }
    }
});
```

The functions .children(), .append, and clone all seem to be coming from jQuery. I know Angular provides its own jQuerylite which has some parts of jQuery, is that what tElement is using? Or is it using all of jQuery.

As a side question, why must one use content.clone()? It doesn't work with just 
tElement.append(content) even though when I log content and content.clone() they appear to be the same h1.

Comment: full details in docs. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element jQlite has many of the jQuery methods and they are listed in this docs link

Comment: as a side question, why does one have to use .clone? why can't one just do tElement.append(content); –

Comment: actually that looks strange , seems like clones are appended but then whole element gets replaced on next line

Comment: thats intentional its to replace the <double> tag in the html, so all thats left are the children. i will post the html

Comment: Aren't the clones now a part of children once they are appended?

Comment: yes...had a brain freeze because of the cached children above it

Comment: tElement.append(content) does not copy elements...it only moves them. Won't visually move them since they would be set in same place so effectively does nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its depends, when you are loading the `jQuery` API.

If `jQuery` is loaded before Angular, you will get `jQuery` compiled DOM (Preferred way), otherwise you will `jQLite` compiled DOM.

If you have loaded jQuery loaded later Angular, you can access jQuery API directly, you need to recompile it with jQuery again by having wrapping that element in `$` function like `$(element)`.

Comment: as a side question, why does one have to use .clone? why can't one just do

tElement.append(content);